# Can't apt-get install packages on pythonanywhere

Tags: django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy a django project to pythonanywhere. I'm using this package in my project:

https://github.com/algoo/preview-generator

In order for preview-generator to work it has the following requirements:

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev python3-pythonmagick inkscape xvfb poppler-utils libfile-mimeinfo-perl qpdf libimage-exiftool-perl ufraw-batch ffmpeg
```

The Bash console in Pythonanywhere won't let me install packages as root. Is there any way for me to install these required packages on the pythonanywhere server?

I read that the best you can do is make a request to the pythonanywhere team to have the packages added in future versions. Is this still the case?

Comment: why you want an alternative, you tried apt-get command?

Comment: Yeah it says you need to be root to use apt-get, but when I looked in the PA docs it says you don't have access to root on their servers.

Comment: You have to use sudo before the command

Comment: I should have clarified in my post. The bash console in PA won't let you gain root access. Using sudo or su - gives a warning that permission denied no access to root.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here: yes, you still need to ask to have the packages included in future system images.  It looks like we already have some of them, but not all of them.